# AWS Sagemaker - using cross validation instead of dedicated validation set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cross-validation, amazon-sagemaker

When I train my model locally I use a 20% test set and then cross validation. Sagameker seems like it needs a dedicated valdiation set (at least in the tutorials I've followed). Currently I have 20% test, 10% validation leaving 70% to train - so I lose 10% of my training data compared to when I train locally, and there is some performance loss as a results of this.

I could just take my locally trained models and overwrite the sagemaker models stored in s3, but that seems like a bit of a work around. Is there a way to use Sagemaker without having to have a dedicated validation set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker seems to allow a single training set while in cross validation you iterate between for example 5 different training set each one validated on a different hold out set. So it seems that SageMaker training service is not well suited for cross validation. Of course cross validation is usually useful with small (to be accurate low variance) data, so in those cases you can set the training infrastructure to local (so it doesn't take a lot of time) and then iterate manually to achieve cross validation functionality. But it's not something out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can you please elaborate which tutorials you are referring to when you say "SageMaker seems like it needs a dedicated validation set (at least in the tutorials I've followed)."

SageMaker training exposes the ability to separate datasets into "channels" so you can separate your dataset in whichever way you please.

See here for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container.html#your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container-trainingdata